# asp.net mvc client side validation password field in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, firefox

Asp.net mvc 2 seems to not clear a required validation error for a password field in firefox.

- in both firefox and chrome:
  submit the form client side validation works and it says 'password is required'
- In chrome, I add a value to the password field and the client error is cleared.
- In firefox,I add a value to the password field and the client error is NOT cleared.

When I change the code to render a textbox, both browsers work.
i.e. <%= Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password) %> from <%= Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password) %>

Is this a bug in MVC?  OR am I missing something?  Thanks in advance.

---

update...

I couldn't replicate on a new form.. The issue was due to the jquery watermark plug in. I believe there is a bug in one of the two scripts (jquery watermark or Microsoft ajax validation) I was using this plugin for watermarks: http://updatepanel.net/2009/04/17/jquery-watermark-plugin/

Comment: I'd widely guess you are missing something in your project. Try creating a blank page for same tests.

Comment: Thanks.  I jumped the gun on this, couldn't replicate on a new form..  The issue was due to the jquery watermark plug in.  I believe there is a bug in one of the two scripts (jquery watermark or Microsoft ajax validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a conflict between http://updatepanel.net/2009/04/17/jquery-watermark-plugin/ and microsoft ajax validation.